# Always Encrypted SQL Server : How to insert / updated using C++ code?

Tags: sql-server, insert, always-encrypted, c++

I have set the Always Encrypted option to my table columns.
Now I need to insert or update my table from my C++ Client application.
I know that we need to declare params and use them for Always Encrypted.
From SSMS I am able to do so without any issues.
However, when I try using C++ code, it fails.

Say, for example, my table contains two columns that have data type int.
I connect to my database using the below connection string:

```
"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=192.122.200.200,1433;Encrypt=no;Trusted_Connection=no;ColumnEncryption=Enabled;DATABASE=AlwaysEncrypted;UID=sa;PWD=;";
```

I create the below SQL query string:

```
CString csQStrInsert = L"declare @val1 int = 3; declare @val2 int = 3; insert into [dbo].[Table_AlwaysEncrypted] ([col1], [col2]) values (@val1, @val2);";
```

And call `pDatabase->ExecuteSQL(csQStrInsert);`

However, this throws exception with the following info:

*Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@val1'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '1' expects it to be DETERMINISTIC, or PLAIN TEXT.*

Can someone help me out? There is mostly no help when it comes to C++ code for Always Encrypted.

[Trialed code that still fails in SQL Execute:]

```
SQLHENV henv = SQL_NULL_HENV;
    SQLHDBC hdbc1 = SQL_NULL_HDBC;
    SQLHSTMT hstmt = SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
    SQLRETURN rc = 0;

    RETCODE retcode;
    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, NULL, &henv);
    if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
    {
        retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER); // Notify ODBC that this is an ODBC 3.0 app.
        if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc1); // Allocate ODBC connection handle and connect. 
            if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
            {
                SQLCHAR retconstring[1024];
                SQLWCHAR connstr[] = L"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.555.128,1433;Encrypt=no;Trusted_Connection=no;ColumnEncryption=Enabled;DATABASE=AEncrypted;UID=Supervisor;PWD=;";
                retcode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc1, NULL, connstr, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*)retconstring, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
                if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
                {               
                    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
                    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
                    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc1, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
                    {
                        CString csMsg = message;
                    }
                    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc1, &hstmt); // Allocate statement handle. 
                    if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    std::string queryText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_AEncrypted] ([col1], [col2]) VALUES (?, ?);";
    rc = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR *)queryText.c_str(), SQL_NTS);

    SQLINTEGER val1 = 123;
    SQLINTEGER val2 = 456;
    SQLINTEGER cbNull = SQL_NULL_DATA;

    rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, SQL_DESC_PRECISION, 0, (SQLPOINTER)val1, 0, &cbNull);
    rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, SQL_DESC_PRECISION, 0, (SQLPOINTER)val2, 0, &cbNull);

    rc = SQLExecute(hstmt);

    // Clean up.  
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
    SQLDisconnect(hdbc1);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc1);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
```

Comment: You cannot use local variables for Always Encrypted columns, they *must* come from client-side parameters. The client driver needs to have access to the relevant certificate. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#data-insertion-example In SSMS it works because SSMS parses your script and pulls out the variables into paramters

Comment: Dupe on [so] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74214512/always-encrypted-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Charlieface is correct, SSMS (with the options enabled) will parse and parameterize for you.

If you want to use C++ and ODBC (taken from your connection string) then you'll need to have a parameterized query and use the appropriate preparation. In this case it would be to use [SQLBindParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function?view=sql-server-ver16). There is an example at the bottom of the page which should help, additionally there is a [developer resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16) on the SQL Docs page which can help and covers your exact scenario.

Much as Charlieface has already pointed out, Always Encrypted requires the client-side driver to do all the work. It would make sense to have a [quick read up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) on it.

Comment: I tried the above approach but it did not work out. Basically I am trying to insert values into two columns of integer data type. SQLExecute fails for me with the error message message2 = 0x012fcac0 L"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '0x204f'." Will add the code in question above. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.  [Dev environment  Windows 10 Visual Studio 2013]

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in my SQLDriverConnect.
It is now working.

```
SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle = 0;
SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle = 0;
SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle = 0;
SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle2 = 0;
SQLRETURN retcode = 0;
SQLWCHAR retconstring[1024];

retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle);
retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLWCHAR connstr[] = L"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.555.128,1433;Encrypt=no;Trusted_Connection=no;ColumnEncryption=Enabled;DATABASE=AEncrypted;UID=Supervisor;PWD=;";
retcode = SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnectionhandle, NULL, connstr, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*)retconstring, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle2);

SQLWCHAR *query = _T("INSERT INTO Table_AEncrypted(col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)");
retcode = SQLPrepare(sqlstatementhandle2, query, SQL_NTS);

SQLINTEGER val1 = 222;
SQLINTEGER val2 = 444;

retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlstatementhandle2, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &val1, 0, NULL);
retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlstatementhandle2, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &val2, 0, NULL);

retcode = SQLExecute(sqlstatementhandle2);

SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle2);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
SQLDisconnect(sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);
```